# PHP and Nginx, suddenly extremely slow over SSL but perfect over HTTP

Tags: php, ssl, nginx, timeout

A site of mine just started responding painfully slow over HTTPS, TTFB is upwards of 20 seconds, and every 3rd load or so, I receive a 504 Gateway Time-Out.

Without SSL, whole site loads in sub 1 second.

I cannot find anything that would be causing this, and I'm at a loss as to why SSL-only would be timing out. Looking for direction for investigation.

Comment: 20 seconds is a quasi eternity ! could you have some DNS misconfiguration that only reveals its ugly self with `https` ?

Comment: I believe that you could get a better on-topic help in ServerFault. Sounds like an epic misconfiguration more than a programming question but yes, I agree with @YvesLeBorg 20 seconds is an eternity and then some

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was a DNS misconfiguration; the web host corrected their own mistake and now everything is fine.